# Dicharge a Photoflash Capacitor in a coil

Tags: capacitor, coil, discharge

I am trying to do the coin tosser according to [this pdf](http://downloads.deusm.com/designnews/499-Get_the_Build_Instructions.pdf#page=13) (result [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8yn2uCeY0E))

So the circuit is supposed to be this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy24PE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However when I did it and tried to charge the 330V Capacitor, it wasn't charging it anymore.
But when I removed the Diode D, it did charge it, but then the discharge in the coil wasn't working great.... and when I put the diode back in position there was a spark. (I took a 400V regular diode with the white band attach to the + circuit part)

Thank you for your help!

NB: Be advised that this circuit is dangerous, and you can get shocked if you don't be careful.

Comment: Your diode labeled rectifier is in wrong direction.

Comment: @soosaisteven no I don't think so, I have checked on a disposal camera circuit and the black part faces the negative pole of the condensator

Comment: If your rectifier is in correct orientation, then your SCR is not...